# how to add folder to javascript path item.setSavePath in electron

Tags: javascript, electron

item.setSavePath(app.getAppPath()+ '/tmp/' + item.getFilename()) this format not working but item.setSavePath(app.getAppPath()+ '/' + item.getFilename()) is working, how to add the folder "tmp" to the path?

Comment: What's "not working" about it?

Comment: fixed when adjusting relative path